# I need more accurate positon in my location now its like 24.0 and i want 24.1235152

Tags: java, android, android-location

I want it to be more accurate in calculations.

Now is like a 24.0, but I want it to be 24.1234512563.

I don't know what I need to change. I was trying to change from `int` to `double` but it is not working.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ShowLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_location);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        // default
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("lokalizacja nie dostępna");
            longitudeField.setText("lokalizacja nie dostępna");
        }
    }

    /* Request updates at startup */
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    /* Remove the locationlistener updates when Activity is paused */
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double lat = (long) (location.getLatitude());
        double lng = (long) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider,
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question is very unprecise, but your problem seems pretty obvious: You are doing a very weird cast here:

```
double lat = (long) (location.getLatitude());
double lng = (long) (location.getLongitude());
```

Why would you cast this to long? There you lose your precision.

I assume that `.getLatitude()` and `.getLongitute()` both return `double`, like *24,123*. Now you cast this value to `long`, which turns it to only *24*. And now, as the variable you assign the value to is of type `double`again, you transform *24* to *24.000*.

Comment: I was thinking that long will be better than int. And more information will show on my screen. What i want to achieve is more accurate position like 24.xxxxxx now i have 24.0 and nothink more

Comment: Thx a lot :) now i understand :)

Comment: Unrelated: what a shame, looks like the whole question was deleted.